# Error "Expected identifier when parsing expression, got '+'

Tags: logic, counter, roblox

I was trying to make a counter that goes up when you press m1 but it gives me the error message Expected identifier when parsing expression, got '+'... Even when I add another plus so its ++ it doesnt work.

```
local PCounter = 0
if Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
local PCounter + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You're basically saying to Roblox Studio 'create a local variable plus 1'. Doesn't make a lot of sense does it?

To add a number (in this case 1) to a variable there's 2 methods. The first one is longer but may result more useful in cases where complex operations may be calculated, the second is shorter and usually used with only 1 number or simple operations.
For the long one, you can set the variable to itself plus 1. You'd do it like this:

```
PCounter = PCounter + 1
```

With this you're saying 'set PCounter to PCounter plus 1'.

The short method can be accomplished with "compound assignment" operators. For instance, += -= /= *= etc.. are all compound assignment operators. So, your code would look like this:

```
PCounter += 1
```

This is pretty much the same as the long method, but a lot shorter.

Hopefully this will help you with future codes as well!